# RabbitMQ Java Client Connection Timeout

Tags: rabbitmq

I am using the same client connection properties for Producer and Consumer. But while I am able to Produce messages to RabbitMQ, getting following error for Consumer side. I have read many solutions all say check out connection properties, firewall etc. But I have working producer.
Consumer side connection codes:

```
 String userName = "myuser"; // not guest
    String password = "mypassword"; // not guest
    String virtualHost = "/";
    String hostName = "one_of_rbmq_ip";
    Integer portNumber = 5672;

    ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
    // "guest"/"guest" by default, limited to localhost connections
    factory.setUsername(userName);
    factory.setPassword(password);
    factory.setVirtualHost(virtualHost);
    factory.setHost(hostName);
    factory.setPort(portNumber);

    Connection conn = factory.newConnection();
```

Error gives at last line (conn)

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:81)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:476)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:218)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:162)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:394)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:606)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.SocketFrameHandlerFactory.create(SocketFrameHandlerFactory.java:60)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.recovery.RecoveryAwareAMQConnectionFactory.newConnection(RecoveryAwareAMQConnectionFactory.java:63)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.recovery.AutorecoveringConnection.init(AutorecoveringConnection.java:160)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:1216)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:1173)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:1131)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:1294)
    at Condumer2.main(Condumer2.java:25)
```

Answer (score 1):

I have changed my code like following it worked

```
    Address[] addrArr = new Address[]{ new Address("10.28.94.117", 5672)
                , new Address("10.28.94.118", 5672)
                , new Address("10.28.94.119", 5672)
        };

        ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
        factory.setUsername("rabbitmq");
        factory.setPassword("qa");

        Connection connection = factory.newConnection(addrArr);
        Channel channel = connection.createChannel();
```